# Check for a CSS class has a property - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have these elements;

```
<div class="preview">
    <div class="title" style="display:block">
</div>

<div class="preview">
    <div class="title" style="display:none">
</div>

<div class="preview">
    <div class="title" style="display:none">
</div>
```

I want to add a class to the preview, if the title is 'display:none'.

Please help me short this.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.title').is(':not(:visible)').closest('.preview').addClass('foo');
```

Note the `:not(:visible)` will catch any `.title` elements who are hidden due to the `visibility` or `display` properties. If you only want to catch `display: none` try this:

```
$('.title').each(function() {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).closest('.preview').addClass('foo');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.preview').has('.title:hidden').addClass('yournewclass');
```

Comment: The logic here is the wrong way around - he wants to add the class if the title is NOT visible